# The VisibleIndex of DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

```
gv = (GridView)emgrid.MainView;
//for testing
gv.Columns[1].Caption = "hello";
string caption = gv.Columns[1].Caption;
gv.Columns[1].VisibleIndex = 10;
int visibleindex = gv.Columns[1].VisibleIndex;
```

caption is changed into "hello" but the visibleindex changed into 9 not 10.

Why and how to solve,Thanks

Comment: How many columns are in the grid (`gv.Columns.Count`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `gv.Columns[1].VisibleIndex` was lower than 10 before the assignment. If so, then this kind of behavior is documented for [`GridColumn.VisibleIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.VisibleIndex.property):

> When you move a column forward (i.e., assign a new visible index that is higher than the current visible index), the current column is moved to the position before the column whose VisibleIndex equals the assigned value. **So, the actual visible index will be the assigned value minus one**. ...

So for forward moved `VisibleIndex = 10;` unintuitively sets `VisibleIndex` to 9. You'll need to pass 11 to set it to 10.

Comment: Yes,gv.Columns[1].VisibleIndex was lower than 10 before the assignment and I plus 1 more to 11 and the colum shown at the right place,thanks a lot